# One To One Mapping Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I've a question about One to One unidirectional Mapping in Spring Boot.
I've a Customer class with a One to One unidirectional mapping to an Address class.

But when I try to associate a new customer with an existing Address, the database is updated.
So two Customers are now associated with the one Address.

As I understand it only one Customer should be associated with one unique Address. Do I understand the concept correctly, or am I doing something wrong in Spring Boot/ Spring Data JPA/ Hibernate?

**Customer**

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private Long cId;
    private String cName;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="aid")
    private Address cAddr;
    :
}
```

**Address**

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    private Long aid;
    private String town;
    private String county;
    :
}
```

**data.sql**

```
insert into address values (100, "New York", "NY");
insert into customer values (1, "John Smith", 100);
```

**Application.java**

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    Customer c1 = new Customer((long)5, "Mr. Men");
    Optional<Address> a100 = ar.findById((long)100);
    c1.setcAddr(a100.get());
    cr.save(c1);
}
```

**Database**
[image: Both Customers have aid 100]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options on how to make @OneToOne relation: unidirectional and bidirectional: [see hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one).

When you scroll down a little bit you will find the following:

> When using a bidirectional @OneToOne association, Hibernate enforces the unique constraint upon fetching the child-side. If there are more than one children associated with the same parent, Hibernate will throw a org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

It means that you'll have the exception only on fetching and when you have a bidirectional association. Because Hibernate will make an additional query to find the dependent entities, will find 2 of them, which doesn't fit @OneToOne relation and will have to throw an exception.

One way to "fix" uniqueness for your entities, is to make `cAddr` unique:

```java
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="aid", unique=true)
private Address cAddr;
```

If you create your db tables, by [setting hbm2ddl property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha) this will add a unique constraint to the `aid` column.

I really recommend to read the following:

1. [@OneToOne javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html) itself provides examples of how to do everything correctly (for you Examples 1 and 2 are the most useful)
2. Check [Vlad's blog about @OneToOne](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). It must be the best you can find. At least jump to the chapter "The most efficient mapping" and implement it bidirectional and sharing the PK, using `@MapsId`.

Also maybe you will come up to the idea to use @ManyToOne option (at least i can imagine that customer can have multiple addresses)

Answer (score 0):

This is not `One-to-Many` relation. It's `One-to-Many` as *One* object has *multiple* related objects. [Checkout this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Example:

### Post.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String postHeader;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addComment(Comment comment) {
        comments.add(comment);
    }

    public void removeComment(Comment comment) {
        comments.remove(comment);
    }

    // equals() and hashCode()
}
```

### Comment:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "postcom_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String text;

    // equals() and hashCode()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out step "3. Uni-directional one-to-one mapping demonstration" at this [site](https://www.javaspringclub.com/hibernate-one-to-one-uni-directional-mapping-with-annotations/) basically carbon copy of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it doesn't answer the question of how in a one-to-one mapping 2 rows from one table can map to the same row of another table.
Unless I've understood a one-to-one mapping incorrectly?